# Sum of row Depending on data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which store Customerid, amount and vouchartype this is a transaction table which store multiple entry for a single customer. vouchartype is 'D' for debit and 'C' for Credit and all amount have positive value. Now I want to sum of Individual customer debit value should be subtract from Credit value.

Please help me

Comment: Show your current Op and Expected OP as well as your query

Comment: thank for the comments, My problem resolve by ElectricLlama.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. Everything other than 'C' is considered positive. You might need to reverse the sign depending on what you need.

```
SELECT 
Customerid, 
sum(case when vouchartype = 'C' THEN -amount ELSE amount END) As AMount
FROM YOurTable
GROUP BY Customerid
```